# Square OAuthApi: renew and revoke access tokens

Tags: api, oauth, square-connect

I am attempting to renew and revoke Square OAuth access tokens using the [recently released OAuthApi](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/releases/tag/2.20180712.2). The problem I am running into is `[HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request] ... "message": "missing authorization header"`.

Looking at the [`renewTokenWithHttpInfo()`](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Api/OAuthApi.php#L182) and [`revokeTokenWithHttpInfo()`](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Api/OAuthApi.php#L288) methods, I don't see where the `Authorization: Client [secret]` header is set, nor is there an obvious way to pass in the application client secret when using [`renewToken()`](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Api/OAuthApi.php#L165) or [`revokeToken()`](https://github.com/square/connect-php-sdk/blob/master/lib/Api/OAuthApi.php#L272).

What am I missing?

Comment: Here is an example not using the SDKs: https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/oauth-with-php-part-two-refreshing-revoking-tokens-9ae065537c41

Answer (score 0):

This was answered for Python in the Square Dev Slack Channel.

Before you make the API call, you need to set both the Application Secret and the Header Prefix.

Import the necessary SDK elements:

```
from squareconnect.apis.o_auth_api import OAuthApi
from squareconnect.models.renew_token_request import RenewTokenRequest
```

Create your OAuth API Instance:

```
oauth_api = OAuthApi()
```

Set these two variables:

```
oauth_api.api_client.configuration.api_key['Authorization'] = <Your Application Secret>
oauth_api.api_client.configuration.api_key_prefix['Authorization'] = 'Client'
```

New instance of RenewTokenRequest:

```
renew_token_request_body = RenewTokenRequest()
```

Feed it the Access Token you want to renew:

```
 renew_token_request_body.access_token = <The Access Token to Renew>
```

Then make your API Call (your Square App ID is also called your Client ID):

```
response = oauth_api.renew_token(<Your Square App ID>, renew_token_request_body)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem in a recent project. Something like this will set the default configuration and revoke a token using the PHP SDK:

```
function revokeToken( $oauthToken ) {

    $application_id = [YOUR APP ID];
    $application_secret = [YOUR OAUTH SECRET];
    $local = [TRUE or FALSE];

    // set up default authorization
    \SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey( 'Authorization', $application_secret );

    // setting 'Client' here vs. the default 'Bearer' revoked the token correctly
    \SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKeyPrefix( 'Authorization', 'Client' );

    // if you're testing on localhost, disable SSL checks using your own code
    // for production make sure $local is FALSE
    if ( $local ) {
        \SquareConnect\Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setSSLVerification( FALSE );
    }

    // Create an OAuth API client
    $oauthApi = new \SquareConnect\Api\OAuthApi(); 
    $body = new \SquareConnect\Model\RevokeTokenRequest();

    // Set the POST body
    $body->setClientId( $application_id ); // main application ID
    $body->setAccessToken( $oauthToken ); // the OAUTH token of the merchant to remove

    try {
        $result = $oauthApi->revokeToken( $body );
    } catch ( Exception $e ) {
        Log::Error( 'Exception when calling OAuthApi->revokeToken: ' . $e->getMessage() );
        throw new Exception( "Error Processing Request: Token revocation failed!", 1 );
    }

    return;
}
```

}

See https://developer.squareup.com/docs/oauth-api/cookbook/revoke-oauth-tokens for more on how to include the SDK and config file (if needed).